# Why do you have to specify the data type when declaring variables?

Tags: programming-languages

In most coding languages (if not all) you need to declare variables. For example in C# if its a number field then

```
int PhoneNumber
```

If I'm using normal English language I do not need to declare `PhoneNumber` as `int` to use it. For example if I ask my friend Sam to give me his phone number I say:

> "Sam give me the phonenumber"

I wouldn't say

> "Char(20) Sam give me the int phoneNumber"

Why do we have to specify data type at all?

Comment: That's because English has implicit typing - so _yourPhoneNumber_ is implicitly typed as a __PhoneNumber__ - humans also have dynamic memory allocation... ;)

Comment: You and Sam knows that a phone number consists of digits and you would be surprised to find a letter in it.  Computers don't and need to be told.

Comment: And when I hear numbers like 1-800-JIMBO in movies, my thought is: How is that a *number*? O.o

Comment: You shouldn't declare phoneNumber as int. In most programming languages this will delete leading zeros.

Comment: And yet, whenever you have a form from your local bureaucrat, it will do exactly this - fixed-length fields, with complex validation requirements. Why? If you can answer that, you're pretty close to your "why do some programming languages do this?" answer :)

Comment: @Aron_dc Not to mention # and * signs which do (rarely) occur in phone numbers.

Comment: Originally, for efficiency. "int i;" means i needs to be the size of an int. "var i;" means i needs to be at least the size of a pointer (which is possibly bigger than an int). Some platforms will then allocate an int (with the allocation overhead being several times the size of the int) and store a pointer to it. Some platforms are smart enough to pack the int into the pointer space, but they can't do that for all types (e.g. doubles)

Comment: If you needed to have the full international form of the phone number starting with `+`, you would probably say so. As such, you would have declared the type required, as the implicit typing wouldn't suffice.

Comment: It prevents such nonsense as `Sam = phoneNumber + address + email + age + height + hairColor`.  A human reading that might understand that these are several pieces of information about Sam, but a computer would have no idea what to do with them.

Comment: Whatever programming language you are in, you will need some sort of representation of the data type. Maybe that will be an `int`, or maybe you will have defined your own `phoneNumber` data type. Maybe someone else defined a subtype to your `phoneNumber` type. How could the language determine which one it is?

Comment: @HorusKol: humans have not only dynamic memory allocation, but also a highly nonconservative garbage collector...

Comment: "Most coding languages?" [I would](https://www.python.org/) [like to](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) [challenge](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) [your](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) [assumption](http://php.net/). [Have](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) [some](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/mt173057.aspx) [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Dynamically_typed_programming_languages).

Comment: Seems to me that in the 'plain english' example, `phonenumber` is the type and the variable name is not specifed. The code for that would be `me.KnowledgeBase.Add(Sam.GetPhonenumber())`.

Comment: Because when I make a spalling error, I want want to have to spend hours debugging the software.

Comment: "Sam give me the phonenumber" - "55657". You go home, try it, and realize that it does not work because you and Sam live in different area codes. If Sam gave you a defined structure that enforces "number", "areaCode" and "country" you would not have had that problem.

Comment: most (if not all) scripting languages ls JS, VBS, bat, cmd, python, perl, ruby... don't specify the type when declaring

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system, https://www.quora.com/Why-do-programming-languages-use-type-systems

Comment: No, not all. And even not "in most" either.

Comment: "Sam give me the phone**number**", doesn;t this explicitly ask for a datatype (number)?

Comment: Phone numbers must be stored as strings, not ints.

Comment: I would say that in English we use almost exclusively types, and not variable names. "Phone number" is the type of thing you are asking for. You're asking someone to infer the value from the type, not the other way around.

Comment: a `phone number` is not actually a `Number` it is a `String` that just happens to all be `digits` in your example. Ten numbers in a row is not automatically a `phone number`. now `(123) 456-7890` is a `phone number` because of the explicit formatting. `1234567890` does not imply anything about it being a `phone number`. This entire question is based on a flawed assumption.

Answer (score 79):

> In most coding languages (if not all) you need to declare variables.
>
> […]
>
> Why do we have to specify data type at all?

Those are two independent questions:

- Why do we need to declare variables?
- Why do we need to declare types?

Incidentally, the answer to both is: we don't.

There are plenty of statically typed programming languages where you don't need to declare types. The compiler can infer the types from the surrounding context and the usage.

For example, in Scala you can say

```scala
val age: Int = 23
```

or you could just say

```scala
val age = 23
```

The two are *exactly* equivalent: the compiler will infer the type to be `Int` from the initialization expression `23`.

Likewise, in C♯, you can say either of these, and they both mean the exact same thing:

```csharp
int age = 23;
var age = 23;
```

This feature is called *type inference*, and many languages besides Scala and C♯ have it: Haskell, Kotlin, Ceylon, ML, F♯, C++, you name it. Even Java has limited forms of type inference.

In dynamically typed programming languages, variables don't even have types. Types only exist dynamically at runtime, not statically. Only values and expressions have types and only at runtime, variables don't have types.

E.g. in ECMAScript:

```ecmascript
const age = 23;
let age = 23;
```

And lastly, in a lot of languages, you don't even need to declare variables at all. e.g. in Ruby:

```ruby
age = 23
```

In fact, that last example is valid in a number of programming languages. The exact same line of code would also work in Python, for example.

So,

- even in statically typed languages where variables have types, you don't necessarily have to declare them,
- in dynamically typed languages, variables don't have types, so obviously you *can't* even declare them,
- in many languages, you don't even have to declare variables

Comment: Plus one for explaining both type inference and dynamic typing (late binding)

Comment: Regarding type inference, many languages, including ML-based languages, use [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system).  Lambda calculus is magic.

Comment: This is great info about misconceptions behind the question, but still *leaves the question unanswered.* The question, more properly, is *why do we have to specify the data type when declaring variables **in languages that require that?*** Why were they designed way? There are good answers to that question, and while elaborating on alternatives broadens the OP's horizons and is very good, that doesn't seem complete to me.

Comment: @KRyan: if you want to know why a certain language designer made a certain language design choice, you will have to ask that language designer, I'm afraid. I cannot tell you why the designers of C♯ decided against type inference, nor can I tell you why they later changed their minds. Language design is heavily opinionated and often comes down to taste. If, OTOH, you want to know about the specific trade-offs involved, the answer would basically be a re-print of Prof. Pierce's *Types and Programming Languages* which is much too broad for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, I think some inclusion of the idea that explicitly specifying type has benefits, including some examples, would dramatically improve this answer. It does not need to reprint a book, though a reference to a book for more reading is good, but it should at least touch upon the topic.

Comment: The reasons I write types are: a) some types cannot be inferred and b) machine-checked documentation. For an example, polymorphic type inference is impossible for Haskell.

Comment: Even in dynamic languages you may declare types e.g., Python has [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The question is not "why may I declare types", but "why do I *have* to declare types", and in Python, you *don't* have to declare types. Also, the question is about types of variables, and Python *does not* support type annotations of variables, only functions. And lastly, while type annotation *syntax* is part of the language, *types* aren't – they are provided by third-party libraries.

Comment: JörgWMittag: as @KRyan already said, the answer "you don't have to" is not very interesting (it is trivially obvious -- many languages allow to omit the type declarations in some cases). The question "why would you want to declare types" is much more interesting and better reflect the spirit of the original question (your answer reminds me of the joke: ["where we are?" -- "you are in a hot-air balloon!"](http://beenglish.ru/jokes/7.shtml)).  You don't need to know what a designer of a specific language thought at the time, to provide some good reasons in favor of type declaration.

Comment: I'm really currious how you concider C++ supporting type infereing. Unless by tiype inference you mean that there are multiple type names for the same byte size. But especially C++ even requires memory allocations to be explicitely casted and when ever you do an ambiguous asignment it is at least warned about and if there are ambiguousitys on equal ranking it is even a error. So while you could be correct (I absolutely doubt!) I would be pretty much interested in how it works to leave explicit types away in C++ where everything depends on these distinct types and its informations

Comment: @Zaibis: `auto i = 1 // i is inferred to type int`, `vector<int> vec; auto itr = vec.iterator(); // itr is inferred to type vector<int>::iterator` and so on. If you want to know how exactly that works, you can look it up in the spec.

Comment: I know the spec pretty well. What you're refering to is called "auto int".This just assumes: Using the `auto` storage specifier (which is by the way pretty obsolete and without any usage) without declaring a type the compiler has to assume it is meant to be integer. So writing `auto i = 1;` is doing the same as writing `auto int i = 1` which is as far as I understand not the same as type inference. I'm not sure how familiar you are with the `C++` specs but I dare to assume you are missunderstanding what `auto` is actually doing. but you examples are no infering but just implicite declarations.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Ok, digging up an old post of myself, I realized that this is supported in C++ since c++11. http://stackoverflow.com/q/34762708/2003898 But you should any way note in that case that just the altest versions do so.

Answer (score 54):

When you use natural language to refer to information, it is not very precise, and in particular, doesn't communicate to others much about your intent.  Similar problems occur when trying to do math in natural language: it just isn't precise enough.

Programming is complex; errors are all too easy to come by.  Types are part of a system of checks that are designed to prevent illegal program states, by detecting error conditions.  Different languages use types differently: some languages use types heavily to detect errors at compile time. Almost all languages have some notion of incompatible types as a runtime error.  Usually a type error indicates a bug of some sort in the program.  When we allow programs to continue despite errors, we likely get very bad answers.  We prefer to stop the program rather than get bad or incorrect answers.

Put another way, types express constraints on the behavior of the program.  Constraints, when enforced by some mechanism, provide guarantees.  Such guarantees limit the amount of reasoning necessary to think about the program, thus simplifying the task of reading and maintaining the program for programmers.  Without types, and their implication of tools (i.e. the compiler) that detect type errors, the programming burden is considerably higher, and thus, more costly.

It is true that (many) humans easily distinguish between a European, United States, and international phone number.  However, the computer doesn't really "think", and would, if told, dial a united states phone number in europe, or vice versa.  Types, for example, are a good way to distinguish between these cases, without having to teach the computer how to "think".  In some languages, we can get a compile time error for trying to mix a European phone number on an American phone system.  That error tells us we need to modify our program (perhaps by converting the phone number to an international dialing sequence, or, by using the phone number in Europe instead), before we even attempt to run the program.

Further, as the computer doesn't think, the name of the field or variable (e.g. `phonenumber`), means nothing to the computer.  To the computer, that field/variable name is just "blah123".  Think about how your program would be  if all variables were "blahxxx".  Yikes.  Well, that's what the computer sees.  Providing a type gives the computer a inkling into the meaning of the variable that it simply cannot infer from its name alone.

Further, as @Robert says, in many modern languages we don't have to specify types as much as we did in the old days, as languages like C# perform "type inference", which is a set of rules to determine the proper type for a variable in context.  C# only provides for type inference on local variables, but not on formal parameters, or class or instance fields.

Comment: RE the sad part: It is impossible to infer type of a publicly accessible member (public field, public method signature), because you can't predict when and how it will be used. Also, type annotations are documentation.

Comment: I think you should highlight/bold this line: `Types are part of a system of checks that ...` since it directly answers the OP on `Why do we have to specify data type at all?` ..

Comment: Note: you answer assumes that a language used to specify types is somehow better at avoiding errors than your regular programming language. It is obviously not so e.g., consider C++ template language that is Turing-complete (and therefore allows to express many error checks) but it is almost unreadable compared to many other Turing-complete languages such as Haskell, Python, and even other parts of C++ itself. Ask yourself why won't you use the same programming language, to express the error checks as the rest of your program (there are good answers in some but not all cases).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's not true - in F#, you can have public methods without specifying their types explicitly. The compiler will infer the types from usage inside the method. For example, the following are valid public method definitions: `static member add x y = x + y`, `member x.Append s = x.Text + s`. In the first case, `x` and `y` will be inferred to be `int`s because of the addition. In the second case they'll be whatever is valid depending on the type of `x.Text` - if it's a `string`, then `s` will be a `string` as well.

I do agree that type annotations are documentation, though.

Comment: "Implicit local types, explicit interface types" is how a **lot** of people program, even in languages like Haskell that allow you to omit (nearly) all types while still having the compiler infer strict types. There are many people who don't consider it sad when a language enforces this practice (as C# does).

Comment: @Ben, ok, great point!  I've removed the emotion.

Answer (score 29):

In addition to the other answers, there is one thing that should be included. Remember that computers are just bits. Say I give you the bytes:

```
26 3A 00 FF
```

What does that *mean*? It's stored this way by the computer, but without any interpretation, it's *just bits*. It could be 4 ascii characters. It could be an integer. It could be some bytes in an array. It could be part of an object. It could be a pointer to where that cat video is buffering. Pretty much all programming languages from assembly on up need *something* to know how to interpret the bits to make them do meaningful computation.

And since the computer can't know the meaning of those bits, it needs you to tell it - either explicitly via type annotations, or implicitly via type inference mechanisms mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: True enough, but to really boggle your mind, realize that the computer is *never* capable of **understanding** what those bits mean—even when you tell it more type annotations.  Your explanations just get turned into even more hex numbers, to "clarify" the first hex numbers.  The significance is all created by people in order to put the intention into the electronics and get them to do what we intend.  Now go say "thank you" to an engineer.  :)

Comment: I spent many years programming on mainframes. With PL/1 this answer makes a LOT of sense. Quite regularly we would be used based storage based on a pointer that was set to the address of another variable of a different data type to access the bytes in a different way. For example PL/1 doesn't support a 1 byte binary numeric field, but we would base a 1 character variable at the address to allow us to store a 6 byte array storing 6 single byte binary fields (in this case allowing us to save 6 bytes per address - which was important when storage was expensive).

Comment: However, this does *not* require variables to be typed. It is enough to type the *value*.

Comment: The computer is able to understand a lot of possibilities but even the clever compilers needs context to understand. It is not the same the number 0 or "0". Or the String "Dec 31" will be ordered before "May 1" treated as a String but not if treated as a Date. Or take 5/2. It is 2 as an enter but 2.5 as a double.

Also, the type is a security measure against unwanted conversions. Null, NaN, and rounding or overflows might also become a problem. Strong and statically typed languages have some advantages. For example, the compiler helps you detect problems while refactoring.

Comment: @Borjab Did you mean "It is 2 as an _integer_"?

Comment: @RichardEverett Certainly that was a lapsus. Thanks but to late to edit it.

Comment: I thought that all languages supported the Cat Video type automatically? To handle errors, they have values like NotACat and things.

Comment: Actually 0xFF is not a valid ASCII character ;) ASCII is a 7-bit code.

Answer (score 24):

The answer to *why* the computers need this information has to do with **Data Representation**.

**The name of the "data type" is a reference to rules that help the computer store and retrieve information from it's raw state of 0's and 1's in the computer memory.**

For an example, your regular 8-bit ASCII character would be stored in the computer memory (either RAM or Disk) as `01000001` (the uppercase character "A", ASCII code 65) or `00001000` (the percent sign), or any combinations of 0's and 1's in those 8 bits.

For another example, some 8-bit unsigned integer may be stored as `00000101` (the number 5) or `00001000` (the number 8)

Notice how binary representation of 8 and the % character may be the same, but they mean different things because their types are different.

Even the languages which infer the data type, they may not have the rule that "all varibles' types must be declared by the programmer", they have rules like "if your series of characters is enclosed in quotes, it is a string" and many more rules for each data type.

So even these need data types to make sense of what the 0's and 1's mean, so they can for example do the string concatenation function if you try to "add" two characters, or do integer addition if you're trying to add two integers.

In **your story** too, let's say you didn't ask Sam for the phone number but Sam gives you a piece of paper that has "1123581321" written on it. You couldn't be certain if Sam is just a fan of first eight Fibonacci numbers, or if that's a phone number. To make a guess you'll have to take into account the context and cues you have available, like perhaps you asked Sam for a phone number a day ago, or the note says "Call Me", or if you count the digits and find it matches patterns of most phone numbers. Only then you'd know that it's a phone number that you can call and not some digits that you'd punch into a calculator.

Note how these hints that led you to a guess that the number was a phone number are similar to how hints lead a computer language that doesn't require declaration to deduce the type of a value.

Comment: This is the closest answer. It all has to do with memory. You declare the type so the compiler knows how much memory to the application should request at runtime. Knowing how the bits should be interpreted is secondary.

Comment: @GregBurghardt true. For making sense of bits already present as well as putting the bits there in first place after converting given data to binary according to the data type.

Answer (score 10):

In some languages, you don't have to specify the data type.

Languages that support type inference can usually figure out the data type from your usage.  For example,

```
var name = "Ali"
```

is internally typed as a string, because the value is surrounded by quotes.

Some languages don't require you to declare the variable either; the variable is created when it is first used. However, it's considered a best practice to specifically declare your variables, for a number of important reasons; mostly because doing so better expresses your intent.

Comment: The `var name = "Ali"` style is actually common for modern _statically_ typed languages. In statically typed languages, the type is fixed at creation, but it still can be determined by the initializer. The definition of a dynamically typed language is that types attach to values, not variables. Assigning a value to a variable therefore sets the variables's type as well.

Comment: @MSalters: I made a slight adjustment to the wording.

Comment: The irony here is this includes C# with this exact syntax.

Comment: @MSalters _Assigning a value to a variable therefore sets the variables's type as well._ Or that the variable has no inherent type and the interpreter will attempt to apply whatever operation to the value of the variable. Are there any dynamically typed languages where code like the following (Javascript) would not be allowed `var x = 5; x = "";` because the first statement causes `x` to have the "Number" type associated with `x`? Sort of conflicts with _dynamic typing_. And if not, what effect does the type associated with the variable have, beyond the type association with the value?

Comment: @ZevSpitz: The first kind of system isn't dynamically typed, but not typed at all. Your Javascript example isn't dynamically typed, precisely because the Number type cannot change. In a dynamically typed language, `x = "";` changes the _type_ of x to string, even if it was a number previously.

Comment: @MSalters Your words: _The definition of a dynamically typed language is that types attach to values, not variables_ so I can reassign a value of any type to any variable, regardless of the initially assigned type  -- `var x=5; x=""; x= new Date();`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Indeed. The type of x dynamically changes from number to string to date. You could even have `x = (rand() ==0) ? "string" : 5` and then the type of `x` will be random (!)

Comment: @MSalters _The type of `x` ...._ How is this the type of `x` and not the type of the value to which `x` is pointing? Why not just say that `x` has no (inherent) type whatsoever?

Comment: This answer isn't clear enough about the distinction between type inference, where the variable has a type (e.g. `var` in C#); and dynamic typing, where no type is inferred from the value because the variable has no type.

Answer (score 10):

Because that is what the language design specifies. So to answer your question, we need to look at the intent behind explicit typing in languages like C# and C++. (Well, C# does it because C++ does it because C does it, so we need to look at the intent way back then).

First, explicit and static typing provides rigour in coding - specifying a variable to be an integer means that the compiler and software should be surprised and throw an error when you assign a character or string to the variable. Dynamic typing can cause headaches for the unwary (simply look at PHP or javascripts approach to truthiness of things like arrays and empty strings).

You can have static with implicit typing - initializing a variable as a string means that variable should only ever be a string, but my feeling is that this can cause problems for humans reading the code (I tend to assume dynamic typing when there is implicit typing).

Also, it is possible, in some languages, to write something like this pseudocode to initialise a class from a string input:

```
PhoneNumber phoneNumber = "(61) 8 8000 8123";
```

Second, explicit typing also goes hand in hand with memory allocation. An *int* is always so many bytes. A *PhoneNumber* is so many bytes. The compiler can assign an appropriate sized memory block that can then be used later without having to see how much space it will need when you assign a value.

```
PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
...
phoneNumber = "some value from somewhere";
```

Finally, it removes confusion... is 123 an integer or an unsigned integer? They need the same number of bytes, but the maximum value stored in variables of either type is very different...

This is not so say that explicit is better than implicit - but the language design relies on these kinds of choices, and C# would work differently with implicit typing. PHP and javascript would work differently with explicit typing.

Answer (score 6):

Because Sam is smarter than compilers.  For instance, when you say give me the phone number, you don't specify whether you want the country prefix or the the area code whether it is work number where only the last 4 digits are required.  Also, you if you ask for the number of the local pizza joint, you would be able to deal with the answer "pizza4u".

Sam, figures it out from context.  While the compiler can also figure it out from context, Sam will be better at it (and is capable of interrupting the process to ask for clarification).

There are two basic approaches to types and variables, either the variable has a type, in which case actions that aren't allowed by the type are forbidden and prevent compilation, or the value has a type and actions that aren't allowed by the type are caught at runtime.

Each approach has it's advantages and disadvantages.  In general, compiler writers try to minimize the disadvantages and maximize the advantages.  Which is why C# for instance allows `var phoneNumber = GetPhoneNumber();` and will deduce the type of phoneNumber from the signature of GetPhoneNumber.  That means you have to declare the type for the method, but not the variable that receives the result.  On the other hand, there are various type hinting/enforcing projects for javascript.  Everything is a tradeoff.

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of the way the data is stored. Your interaction with Sam would make a better comparison if you were asking so your could write it down but only had eight characters' worth of paper.

> "Sam, give me the phoneNumber."
>
> "5555555555"
>
> "Oh no I'm out of paper. If only I had known ahead of time how much data I was asking for I could have prepared better!"

So instead, most languages make you declare a type, so it will know and prepare ahead of time:

> "Sam, how long is a telephone number?"
>
> "Ten characters."
>
> "Ok, then let me get a bigger piece of paper. Now give me the phoneNumber."
>
> "5555555555"
>
> "Got it! Thanks Sam!"

It gets even hairier when you look at the actual fundamental ways that the data is stored. If you're like me, you have a notebook with miscellaneous notes, numbers just scribbled down, no context or labeling for anything, and you have no clue what any of it means three days later. This is a problem for computers a lot of times, too. Lots of languages have "int" types (int, long, short, byte) and "float" (float, double) types. Why is that necessary?

Well first let's look how an integer is stored, and generally represented within the computer. You're probably aware that at the basic level, it's all binary (1's and 0's). Binary is actually a number system that works exactly like our decimal number system. In decimal, you count 0 to 9 (with infinite implied leading zeroes that you don't write), then you roll over back to 0 and increment the next digit so you have 10. You repeat until you roll over from 19 to 20, repeat until you roll over from 99 to 100, and so on.

Binary is no different, except that instead of 0 to 9, you count 0 to 1. 0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000. So when you type in 9, in memory that's recorded in binary as 1001. This is an actual number. It can be added, subtracted, multiplied, etc, in exactly that form. 10 + 1 = 11. 10 + 10 = 100 (roll over 1 to 0 and carry the 1). 11 x 10 = 110 (and equivalently, 11 + 11 = 110).

Now in the actual memory (registers included), there's a list, array, whatever you want to call it, of bits (potential 1's or 0') right next to each other, which is how it keeps these bits logically organized to make a number greater than 1. Problem is, what do you do with decimals? You can't just insert a piece of hardware in between the two bits in the register, and it would cost way too much to add "decimal bits" in between each pair of bits. So what to do?

You encode it. Generally, the architecture of the CPU or the software will determine how this is done, but one common way is to store a sign (+ or -, generally 1 is negative) in the first bit of the register, a *mantissa* (your number shifted however many times it needs to be to get rid of the decimal) for the following X number of bits, and an exponent (the number of times you had to shift it) for the remainder. It's similar to scientific notation.

Typing allows the compiler to know what it's looking at. Imagine that you stored the value 1.3 in register 1. We'll just come up with our own fancy encoding scheme here, 1 bit for sign, 4 for mantissa, 3 for exponent (1 bit for sign, 2 for magnitude). This is a positive number, so the sign is positive (0). Our mantissa would be 13 (1101) and our exponent would be -1 (101 (1 for negative, 01 = 1)). So we store 01101101 in register 1. Now we didn't type this variable, so when the runtime goes to use it, it says "sure, this is an integer why not" so when it prints the value we see 109 (64 + 32 + 8 + 4 + 1), which is obviously not right.

Not every language requires you to explicitly type, though. C# has a keyword "var" that causes a variable's type to be interpreted at compile time, and other languages like Javascript are totally dynamically typed, to the point that you can store an integer in a variable, then assign it to a boolean, then assign it again to a string and the language keeps track of it all.

But it's a lot easier on the compiler, interpreter, or runtime--and often results in a faster program since it doesn't have to spend valuable resources sorting through the typing of everything--to ask you, the programmer, what kind of data you're giving it.

Answer (score 2):

There are programming languages where you *don't* have to declare data types for your variables. There are even programming languages where you don't have to declare variables before-hand; you can just *use* them, immediately.

The trouble with not declaring variable names is that if you accidentally misspell the name of a variable, you've now accidentally created a new, completely unrelated variable. So when you run your program, you can't figure out why the *hell* that variable you set up suddenly has nothing in it... Until, after many hours of debugging, you realise you typed the damned name wrong! GRRR!!

So they made it so you have to *declare* the variable names you're going to use before-hand. And now when you type a name wrong, you get a compile-time error, which immediately tells you *exactly* where the bug is, before your program even runs. Isn't that so much easier?

Same deal with data types. There are programming languages where you *don't* have to declare what type things should be. If you have a `customer` variable that's actually just a customer's name, not the entire customer object, trying to fetch the customer address from a plain ordinary string... isn't going to work. The entire *point* of static typing is that the program won't compile; it will loudly complain, pointing to the exact place where the problem is. That's *much* faster than running your code and trying to figure out why the hell it's not working.

All of these are features to tell the compiler what you were *intending* to do, so it can check what you *actually* did and make sure it makes sense. That makes it possible for the compiler to *automatically* locate bugs for you, which is a Big Deal.

(Far back in the distant past, you didn't have to declare *subroutines*. You would just `GOSUB` to a particular line number. If you wanted to pass information between subroutines, you would set particular global variables, call your subroutine, and then inspect other variables when the subroutine returns. But that makes it *frighteningly easy* to forget to initialise one of the parameters. So now almost *all* modern programming languages demand that you declare what actual parameters a subroutine takes, so we can check you've specified them all.)

Comment: In C++ you can put "auto x=1" and it knows it's an int. auto y=1.2; auto z = 'Z'; etc

Comment: @QuentinUK In C#, you can put `var x=1` with similar results. But that's nothing; in Haskell, you can write your entire program with no type signatures at all, yet it's all statically typed, and you still get errors if you make a mistake... (Not exactly mainstream though.)

Comment: @QuentinUK But if you write `for (auto i=0; i<SomeStdVector.size(); ++i)` your linter is going to complain because it deduced a *signed* type and you proceed to compare it to an unsigned type. You have to write `auto i=0ul` (putting the type information in explicitly again, so should just write `size_t i=0` in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm using normal English language I do not need to declare PhoneNumber as int to use it. For example if I ask my friend Sam to give me his phone number I say:
>
> "Sam give me the phonenumber"
>
> I wouldn't say>
>
> "Char(20) Sam give me the int phoneNumber"
>
> Why do we have to specify data type at all?

Pop over to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) or [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) and read for a while to get an idea of how humans communicated alogrithms with one another when they want to insure that there is no possibility of misunderstanding. Or read the standard for some mature programming language.

You'll find that defining what kinds of values are allowed to a term *is* part of really precise communications practice even human-to-human.

What you've noticed is that day-to-day interactions are fairly regular and human are pretty fault tolerant, so a misunderstanding about phone numbers is generally avoided by the shared knowledge of the participants.

But have you ever tried to take down a phone number for someone in another country? Did they tell you explicitly how many times to push zero to get to international addressing? Did they tell you their country code? Did you recognize it as such? How many digits did you expect? How many did you get? Did you know how to group the digits? Or even *if* the grouping has significance?

Suddenly the problem is a lot harder and you probably took a lot more care to explicitly check that the number recieved was understood the way the sender meant it.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for declaring types is efficiency.  While an integer could be stored in 1 byte, or 2 bytes, or 4, a program using a very large number of variables might use 4 times the needed memory, depending on what's being done.  Only the programmer knows if a smaller storage space is viable, so he can say so by declaring the type.

Also, dynamically typed objects allow for many possible types, on the fly.  That could incur some overhead "under the hood", slowing down the program compared to sticking with one type all along.

Answer (score 0):

A number of early programming languages (especially Fortran) did not require you to declare variables before use.

This led to a number of problems. One really obvious one is that the compiler can no longer catch simple typographical errors nearly as dependably. If you have code that's supposed to modify an existing variable, but has a typo, you still have perfectly legitimate code that just created (and assigned a value to) a new variable:

```
longVariableName = 1

// ...

longVaraibleName = longvariableName + anotherLongVariableName
```

Now, looking at this in isolation, with my already having mentioned a typo as the source of the problem, it's probably pretty easy to find the typo and the problem here. In a long program, where this is buried in the middle of lots of other code, it's a lot easier to miss.

Even currently with many dynamically typed languages, you can still get the same basic problem pretty easily. Some have some facility to warn you if you assign to a variable, but never read it (which heuristically catches quite a few problems like this) both others don't have such things.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare any variable some space is allocated in the memory,, but the machine( computer in this case )doesn't already know that how much space has to be allocated for that variable.

Example :- you create a program which asks the user to input any number, in this case you have to specify a datatype to store that number, otherwise the machine cannot judge by itself that it should allocate **2 bytes** *or* **2 gigabytes**, if it tries to do allocation by itself then it may result in inefficient memory usage.. 
On the other hand, if you specify the datatype in your program, then after the compilation the machine would allocate proper space according to the need.

Comment: this doesn't seem to offer anything substantial over points made and explained in prior 11 answers

Comment: Gnat you should once again read all the answers thoroughly and see that i've tried to answer this question in a much simpler manner which one can easily understand.

Comment: I just re-checked three most recent answers that were posted about an hour prior to this one and all three seem to be making the same point and per my reading explain it in a simpler manner than here

Comment: Although i didnt responded for the **reward** of your vote but i think you should get to know one thing,, you should downvote an answer because it may give useless or wrong information and if it contains anything offensive. All the answers which have most useful and relevent information will get higher number of upvotes which is sufficient to differentiate between an answer, a good answer and the best answer. Your childish activity of downvoting an answer without any strong reasons will only discourage other people who also want to share their opinion which they think might be useful to others

Comment: Your answer was most likely downvoted because it is not correct. Static typing is not required to help with memory management. There are many languages that allow for dynamic typing, and those languages / environments are able to deal with the memory management issues you mention.

Comment: I know this jay but what you are saying is an exceptional case and the question was asked for some common coding languages ( like C# in this case) where the programmer has to specify the datatype and the obviously one of the main significance of specifying the datatype is that it helps in efficiently allocating the memory. And about those languages referred by you, the input is stored as an object when not already specified. So thats completely an exception